# Adding a form to a product drupal commerce

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, e-commerce, drupal-commerce, commerce

I just want to add a form to a product and after i check the services in that form the amount increases.
[imaeg of the page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lzqzI.jpg)
in the Picture the product price is 7$ but when i add the service it added 10$
then the amount become 17$.
any solution for this,thanks

**-- Drupal commerce**

Answer (score 0):

You can use Commerce Pricing Attributes https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce_pricing_attributes